# Moving android sql lite cursor forward

Tags: android, android-sqlite, cursors

I have a Sql lite table in my application. 
I want to add a cursor to parse the table such that it moves ahead from the current position. 
Main idea is to update all next rows and not previous one.

can anyone give me a example cursor to do so with any loops if required ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) { //Replace this with cursor.moveToPosition(position) to iterate from that position to the end of your cursor, rather than from start to finish.
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()){
          cursor.getInt(0); //get whatever information you require.
          cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    if (!cursor.isClosed()) {
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

There are many ways to achieve this. In the above example, I first check to ensure that the `cursor` isn't empty, and then go through each row one by one until I reach the final row. When done, I call `close()` on the `cursor`.

Comment: Even here , i think it will parse all the rows , right ? or am wrong?

Comment: You are correct. To parse from a later row, you would need to follow the advice from @Arash and use `cursor.moveToPosition(position)` instead of `cursor.moveToFirst()` on the second line of my example. To only parse selected entries, you will need to call `cursor.moveToPosition()` on each. You mat also want to adjust your `query()` in the first instance as well so that you only get the necessary information from the outset.

Comment: Actually your second line can be removed, since you are calling `moveToFirst()` in the `if` condition.

Comment: @miav Are you sure? I understood the statement in the if condition is simply to check and see whether or not the `cursor` has a first row, rather than actually moving to the first row.

Comment: Sure - if the cursor is non-empty, `moveToFirst()` moves-to-first and returns `true` (else, you get `false`). I guess you can also get rid of `getCount() > 0`.